# Как создать скроллбары в turtle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр, gui, turtle

Можно ли подключить scrollbar для окна turtle? Написал генератор лабиринтов. Дело в том, что когда генерируется большой лабиринт, он выходит за пределы экрана и хотелось бы добавить scrollbar, чтобы можно было увидеть его полностью. Как реализовать такую функциональность?

```
def generate_maze(setup, width, height):
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.bgcolor("black")
    wn.title("A Maze Game")
    wn.setup(700, 700)
    # Create class instances
    pen = Pen()
    player = Player()
    treasure = Treasure()

    level_1 = init_maze(walls, width, height)
    recursion(level_1, width, height, 1, 1)

    # Set up the levels
    setup(level_1, pen)

    goto_random_position(player, width, height)
    goto_random_position(treasure, width, height)

    # Handlers
    def up():
        player.go_up(treasure, width, height)

    def down():
        player.go_down(treasure, width, height)

    def left():
        player.go_left(treasure, width, height)

    def right():
        player.go_right(treasure, width, height)

    # Keyboard Binding
    wn.listen()
    wn.onkey(up, "Up")
    wn.onkey(down, "Down")
    wn.onkey(left, "Left")
    wn.onkey(right, "Right")

    # todo скроллбары, новые уровни через таймер
    # Turn off screen updates
    wn.tracer(0)

    # Main Game Loop
    while True:
        wn.update()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Python Turtle window with scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730475/python-turtle-window-with-scrollbars)